# Table doesn't update after search

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have simple table, I searched data and push into table, after that I should click on table(do sorting)  for display data. I need just display after pushing data.

```
    $scope.searchedOwners = [];
    var initSearchedOwnersTable = function () {
        $scope.searchedOwnersTableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 9999999999,
            sorting: {
                UserName: 'asc'
            }
        }, {
            total: 0,
            counts: [],
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                $scope.searchOwnersGridItems = $scope.searchedOwners;
                var count = $scope.searchedOwners.length;
                params.total(count);
                params.count(count);
                $defer.resolve($scope.searchOwnersGridItems);
            }
        });
    }
```

Search and initdata:

```
  $http.post(webApiUrl + '/search?messageTemplateId=' + $scope.messageTemplateId + '&searchQuery=' + $scope.searchQuery).success(function (response) {
            $scope.searchedOwners = response;
            initSearchedOwnersTable();
        }).error(function (response) {
            toaster.pop('error', 'Error occurred while deleting the message template owner');

            $scope.createError = angular.fromJson(response).Message;
        });
```

Also this table showing in the popup, maybe it is reason ...

**update**

I have two table, first on main page and second on popup.
First work good, second after loading data donesn't display this data, and after I click on the top of table (th tag, sorting) all data appear

Comment: can you better explain your question? making a plnkr is best (http://plnkr.co/)

Comment: on the plnkr I can't reporuduce